# Displaying a single text in bold in textview in android

Tags: android-activity, textview

How to show each word in bold for particular seconds in textview in android

Comment: i edited my answer, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this....
But adding a sleep will block your UI so you better use handlers instead of sleep

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Yes you can do that too...

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + Hello + "</b>" +  World));
Thread.Sleep(1000);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Hello + "<b>" + World + "</b>"));
```

You might need other styles supported by TextView, [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) you go.
I hope i helped ;)

Comment: I want to show single word at a time. Ex:"hello world" 1st "HELLO world" should be bold and then after second "hello WORLD" should be bold